# HTML & Bootstrap/ Input with small width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a small input in my HTML file.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<input type="number" id="inputNum" class="input-group" placeholder="number" value="1"> <br />
```

which using bootstrap library.

The problem is that my input is quite wide. I want my input to have a width of ~10% (just one number would be accepted in this field, and I need it small).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look into CSS property `width` or `max-width`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need first to make an container or row for example:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class='col-sm-5'>
        <input type="text" class='form-control ' ></input>
     </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class='col-sm-3'>
             <input type="text" class='form-control '>
         </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

view the example in FullScreen!

Comment: if you still using bootstrap 2 you need to add the span2 or any "number" into the class-> class='span5'

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-1">

<input type="number" id="inputNum" class="input-group" placeholder="number" value="1"> </br>

</div>
```

Comment: The input is still in the same size

Comment: try adding width: 10%